# Word 2010 Templates/Addin/Document passing starting arguments

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-automation

I'm trying to create a word template or addin as a means to enter data into a form. It will be tied to a database through service calls. I'm wondering if there is a way to start this document by passing it an Id for the record it's tied to. I would like to open up the word document from another .NET program passing it the Id so it knows where to get its data. Is this possible? or am I looking at this all wrong?

Comment: could I use environment variables? Or would that be completely nuts?

Answer (score 0):

I use Custom Document Properties to store lot of things about the document.

How to: Create and Modify Custom Document Properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx