# VSTO Word Local storage

Tags: ms-word, vsto

What is the best way to store local information for a VSTO Word2010 Add-in?  Should I write into the users personal folders?  Any special permissions required in this case?

Comment: Try using Custom Document properties 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083528/word-2010-templates-addin-document-passing-starting-arguments/9871524#9871524][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001069/vsto-best-place-to-store-excel-workbook-settings/10001523#10001523][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083528/word-2010-templates-addin-document-passing-starting-arguments/9871524#9871524
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001069/vsto-best-place-to-store-excel-workbook-settings/10001523#10001523

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But then my information is stored inside a specific document.  I was wondering if there was a way store information across documents (for instance adresses, signatures, ...)

Comment: I shared Custom Document Properties by creating the documents from a template and add the CDP to the templates. So all the documents created from the .dotx template would have the CDP's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend two locations:

**ProgramData** - I use this for data applicable to all users.

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);`

**AppData** - Use this location for per-user data.

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`

Comment: Thanks, I forget about this question, but I am writing my data to the AppData folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use database or local folder, factor to consider when opting local folder is all information will get lost if user re install, format or switch his machine.